# How to migrate Kik app to a different URL

Tags: kik

If I want to move my app currently hosted at example.com/a to example.com/b and still have it recognized as the same app by Kik, is it enough to just put in a redirect from /a to /b and/or update the canonical link in the page to the following:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be sufficient. However you should note that the new destination will not have the same ranking as the previous URL, therefore it might take a couple of days for your new app to appear in the same position of the "Top Sites" list.